# On child component state change, update siblings

Tags: reactjs

Partially working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-smoke-ryb2d

**Problem:**
When a user expands/opens a component row, all other rows inside the rows parent component need to be collapsed.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the other sibling rows to collapse.

I tried passing down a handler from the parent to the child that updates the state of the parent which would then in turn propagate down to the children.

**Expected Result**
On expand/open of a row, collapse any other rows that are open inside the parent component that isn't the one clicked

**Code:**

App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Rows from "./Rows";
import Row from "./Row";
import "./styles.css";

export interface AppProps {}

const App: React.FC<AppProps> = props => {
  return (
    <Rows>
      <Row>
        <p>Click me</p>
        <p>Collapse</p>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <p>Click me</p>
        <p>Collapse</p>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <p>Click me</p>
        <p>Collapse</p>
      </Row>
    </Rows>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
Rows.tsx
```

Rows.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Row, { RowProps } from "./Row";

export interface RowsProps {}

const Rows: React.FC<RowsProps> = props => {
  const [areRowsHidden, setAreRowsHidden] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {});

  const handleOnShow = (): void => {};
  const handleOnCollapse = (): void => {};

  const renderChildren = (): React.ReactElement[] => {
    return React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
      const props = Object.assign(
        {},
        (child as React.ReactElement<RowsProps>).props,
        {
          onShow: handleOnShow,
          onCollapse: handleOnCollapse,
          isCollapsed: areRowsHidden
        }
      );
      return React.createElement(Row, props);
    });
  };

  return <>{renderChildren()}</>;
};

export default Rows;
```

Row.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export interface RowProps {
  onCollapse?: Function;
  onShow?: Function;
  isCollapsed?: boolean;
}

const Row: React.FC<RowProps> = props => {
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(props.isCollapsed || true);

  useEffect(() => {}, [props.isCollapsed]);

  const handleClick = (): void => {
    if (isCollapsed) {
      props.onShow();
      setIsCollapsed(false);
    } else {
      props.onCollapse();
      setIsCollapsed(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {React.cloneElement(props.children[0], {
        onClick: handleClick
      })}

      {isCollapsed ? null : React.cloneElement(props.children[1])}
    </>
  );
};

export default Row;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store which row is open inside of `Rows.tsx` and send that value down to its children rather than having the child control that state. You may see this being referred to as lifting state up. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Rows.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Row from './Row'

export interface RowsProps {}

const Rows: React.FC<RowsProps> = props => {
  const [visibleRowIndex, setVisibleRowIndex] = useState<number>(null)

  const renderChildren = (): React.ReactElement[] => {
    return React.Children.map(props.children, (child, index) => {
      const props = Object.assign({}, (child as React.ReactElement<RowsProps>).props, {
        onShow: () => setVisibleRowIndex(index),
        onCollapse: () => setVisibleRowIndex(null),
        isCollapsed: index !== visibleRowIndex
      })
      return React.createElement(Row, props)
    })
  }

  return <>{renderChildren()}</>
}

export default Rows
```

Row.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

export interface RowProps {
  onCollapse?: Function
  onShow?: Function
  isCollapsed?: boolean
}

const Row: React.FC<RowProps> = props => {
  const handleClick = (): void => {
    if (props.isCollapsed) {
      props.onShow()
    } else {
      props.onCollapse()
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      {React.cloneElement(props.children[0], {
        onClick: handleClick
      })}

      {props.isCollapsed ? null : React.cloneElement(props.children[1])}
    </>
  )
}

export default Row
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-hermann-oz2zw

Just a side note: I noticed you're cloning elements and doing something commonly referred to as [prop drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling). You can avoid this by using [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) if you're interested although not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, Dennis.  This is exactly what I needed.  I'll also look into utilizing the context api.